# Click all elements with same class name , selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to click all the elements in a particular class on a web page at the same time

I tried,

```py
for element in driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='nrc6-content-section']"):
    element.click()
```

but it shows an error,

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[128], line 4
      1 #click_all = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='nrc6-content-section']").click()
----> 4 for element in driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='nrc6-content-section']"):
      5     element.click()

TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable
```

How can I slove this?

Comment: Pls try find_elements

Answer (score 0):

Return type of

```
driver.find_element()
```

is `WebElement` - this will return a single element (first in list if more than one is present). Single element is not "iterable" (you cannot iterate over it) - hence the `TypeError: 'WebElement' object is not iterable`.

Use

```
driver.find_elements()
```

instead. It returns a list of elements, list of one if only one element is present. And lists are iterable.